# Type safe class builder with Object.assign typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this example:

```
class DataInit<T> {
    public constructor(init?: Partial<T>) {
        if (init) {
            Object.assign(this, init)
        }
    }
}

class User extends DataInit<User> {
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
}

const user = new User({
    height: '172';
})

console.log(user); // User: { "height": "172"}
```

As you guys can see, I can pass anything to my class User. Even vscode giving me an error, typescript still compiles.
How can I do something similar being type safe?
PS: I just need a class builder to instantiate my test objects on a legible way.
Putting everything on the constructor is pretty bad:

```
class User {
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {} 
}

const user = new User("Dionatan", 29 )
```

typescript playground of the example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwEkB2BLBAeAKgPmgG8BYAKGgugAcBXAIxHWGmAHtUIEAnG4BVrgAp0GBAC5oOAJREyledHQAzaMNEyS5BdoDydAFYBTPgDpIEdAHNUghAAt0EADSL1c7dAC+7it9J+yUHNoAFUIQy5oQwAPBENUABMYeCQ0TCwwiIJNeVoGJmhUMABbQwlOLhFLAG4fanpGZjBLMsKaYroI2v8yQPZOaBpwyIBeQsMAd1DhwRzKO0MrO3FoAHIARgB2ACZVsk8pXtI2DlYQQxMQVktBIYipbqA

Edit: As pointed out by @MikeJerred, we can use the compiler option "noEmitOnError" to stop typescript when trying to compile a property that doesnt exist on the class.
If anyone have other solution, feel free to comment, thanks!

Comment: When you use `Partial`, don't you lose out on the type safety because you can now have a partially initialized user? Also check out [issue #12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

Comment: @Aplet123 actually no, I just tried to remove partial but I still can pass anything to the class.

Comment: `Partial` is one issue, Typescript's lack of exact types is another.

Comment: What typescript version are you using? You example gives an error for me: `Argument of type '{ height: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<User>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'height' does not exist in type 'Partial<User>'.ts(2345)`

Comment: @MikeJerred I have this error but it doesnt stop the compiller, thats the problem, I can still pass anything and it will compile.

Comment: Perhaps you want the compiler option noEmitOnError: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError

Comment: @MikeJerred this actually solves my problem for now, thank you!!!